# CSS placing 3 blocks next to each other

Tags: css

I'm a beginner in CSS, so this is probaly a silly question but still I can't figure it out :). I'm trying to place 3 blocks next to each other with percentages. What i have so far is:

```
    #notification {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #date_pane{
        display: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        width:15%;
    }

    #text_pane{
        display: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        width: 75%;         
    }

    #arrow_pane{
        display: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        width:10%;          
    }
```

The last square stands on the next line. I don't know why? Does somebody know what this happens?

My HTML is:

```
<div id="notification">
    <div id="date_pane"></div>
    <div id="text_pane"></div>
    <div id="arrow_pane"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3r44q/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
#notification{
     font-size:0;
}
```

then set the font to the size you want in all the panes. That or eliminate the whitespace between the divs like such:

```
<div id="notification">
    <div id="date_pane">
    </div><div id="text_pane">
    </div><div id="arrow_pane">
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem here is that the new line between the divs is being interpreted as white-space (since they are now inline-block they are treated as "words") so setting font to 0 makes the space non-existent.

http://jsfiddle.net/vfwKV/1/

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I have this idea that I should avoid floats. Is this true?

Comment: Floats aren't bad, but for what you want they aren't the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think @Don's answer is the most appropriate to the actual issue you're having, while @Pavel and @YD1m have good (popular/traditional) alternative's to "inline" blocks.

However, I wanted to expand/explain a little more on Don's answer since it might not be as obvious to someone new to CSS, HTML and DOM elements.

There's a difference between

```
<div>
    <element />
    <element />
    <element />        
</div>
```

and

```
<div><element /><element /><element /></div>
```

That extra source formatting of newlines, tabs or spaces is seen as a special "white space element" in a sense. And the rules of inline elements is that browsers recognizes up to one space of white space when between inline elements.

In other words, you can think of if similarly to text:

```
<div>
    A   B      C
</div>
<!-- or -->
<div>
    A
    B
    C
</div>
```

We know the browser will output only one space or white space between each character (unless using pre-formatted styling).  However, if what we really wanted was to have "A", "B" and "C" touching each other, we need to write it like:

```
<div>ABC</div>
```

This is what is happening in your example when using "inline-block".  Your inline elements are following the rules of inline elements and adding the extra white space, and that is what @Don means when he says

> put all the pane divs on the same line

So you want to make your HTML like so:

```
<div id="notification"><div id="date_pane"></div><div id="text_pane"></div><div id="arrow_pane"></div></div>
```

Or, as @Pavel and @YD1m mentioned, switch from using `inline-block` to floating the inner elements. This is probably the most common thing most front-end developers/designers do.

Two things to note, if you float inner elements:

1) Use the `clearfix` technique to clear the container element. I like [nicolasgallagher.com's micro solution](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) but if you use a tool like Twitter Bootstrap, you might already have the CSS.  Your code would look like this:

```
<div id="" class="clearfix">
 ...
</div>
```

2) The default box model adds padding and borders to the overall width.  If you use exact widths (like you're doing) but decide to use a border or add some padding inside box, this will cause that box to actual grow larger than expected, pushing the end block(s) over and wrapping to the next line.

I hope that helps!

---

As an addition to my comments above about text nodes between elements, I came across a really creative use of HTML comments to avoid the "text node empty space" issue.  I found this while looking over AnEventApart.com's website.

Lets say you mark up your HTML like such

```
<div>
    <element />
    <element />
    <element />        
</div>
```

This will create "white space" when using `inline-block` because there's white space between the elements and white space between inline elements will always show at least a single space (like characters).  Well, to avoid it and still keep a semi-formatted HTML for developer/designer readability you can use HTML comments to 'wrap' the whitespace away.

```
<div><!--
    --><element /><!--
    --><element /><!--
    --><element /><!--    
--></div>
```

The above trick technically eliminates the white space because one element terminates into a comment which terminates back into the element.  All the newlines and white space between is considered part of the comment.

Of course, this injects extra HTML into your markup, but if you're dealing with a list of 10, 20 or "a lot" of items, this is a much more readable approach.

This would be done by people who like to read over their source code. But with tools like Chrome's Web Developer Toolbar, they auto-format tags with indenting and collapsing, so you should be able to just remove the white space and use that for source code reading.

I just through I'd point that out because it was still an interestingly creative idea.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It is very clear to me now. Even though you say Don answer might be more valid I have to disagree.  This is not against Don or whatever. It just feels to me that when I have to set the Font-size to 0 for layout of elements. It sounds hackish and I think I prefer the float way. If this is not right for any reasons you can provide i will change the correct answer ofcourse.

Comment: Don's answer is more appropriate (validity is something else) because it addressed the actual problem of `inline-block` for layout.  `Float` is an good/better alternative solution to achieve the same/similar result. However, an answer of `use float`, particularly without explanation, is avoiding the problem, not answering it. Which is why I said Don's answer is more appropriate to your question, but not necessary better than using a `float` solution. Cheers! =)

Comment: Damn you are totally right... Thank you for the explanation and it will be in my head when I'll ask another question. Also thanks for the extra info considering Don's answer! I based the solution on personal needs and not on the question!. I will give probs where probs are do! Cheers back to you

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
#date_pane , #text_pane ,#arrow_pane {
  float: left;
}
```

[sample at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcU4L/)

Comment: I thought this was the best answer. I only said first since another person answered the same thing. I didn't made your answer the best because even though your answer solved the problem. This answer made me feel that the css was less hackish. I hope i came across with my explanation since english is not my first tongue. I gave you a thumbs up though

Comment: I understand, just wanted to be sure you selected it for the right reason :)

Answer (score 1):

u have to add float: left

```
#date_pane, #text_pane, #arrow_pane {
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p2x6G/

Answer (score 0):

Well technically what you are asking is impossible.  Block elements are not designed to be next to each other.  Either they have to be wrapped in a table-type environment or, as a previous answer stated, converted to an inline-block element.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is common. I makes since that 75% 15% and 10% add up to 100% so the blocks should fall inline. This does not work in practice however. if you change your %'s to leave at least 2% wiggle room it will work fine. Try 74% 14% and 10%

You would be better of using float's or maybe flexbox. But you can get this to work.

Don't forget that if you use float:left as others have suggested to clear your floats.