# Margin between inline-block elements

Tags: css

I have two inline block elements, and there is a margin between them that I can't seem to control.

How can I get the light blue element to touch the green element in the following JSFiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/oregontrail/XvBa7/1/

```css
.indicator {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    text-align: center;
    background: PaleTurquoise;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.handle {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background: limegreen;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS placing 3 blocks next to each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320625/css-placing-3-blocks-next-to-each-other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `display:inline-block` with `float:left` in `.indicator` and `.handle`

Comment: Yes, the element containing `.indicator` and `.handle` could collapse because those elements are taken out of the float. In this case you would need a clearfix.

Comment: yup agree with  alexej_d add clear:both after .indicator and .handle divs

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possible solutions:
[Fighting the space between inline block elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Inline-block elements are being treated like words and thus are being affected by word spacing.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question here: [CSS placing 3 blocks next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320625/css-placing-3-blocks-next-to-each-other/17320865#17320865)

the solution is to use a wrapper and set `font-size: 0` then reset it in the elements or to eliminate any whitespace between the divs in the html. See the post for a more in depth answer